# In Amazon SageMaker, what (if any) is the difference between an inference and prediction?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Amazon SageMaker has [inference pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-pipelines.html) that process requests for inferences on data. It sounds as though inferences are similar (or perhaps identical) to predictions. Are there any differences between inferences and predictions? If so, what? If not, why not just call it a prediction pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inference usually refers to applying a learned transformation to input data. That learned transformation could be something else than a prediction (eg dim reduction, clustering, entity extraction etc). So calling that process a prediction would be a bit too restrictive in my opinion